# Binary file validity in C++/C++11: checking a binary header

Tags: c++, c++11, validation, memory-management, memory-optimization

I have some code for checking a binary header to see if a binary file is meant to be read by a certain program, and I could use some extra eyes to review it.

Assume the following `typedef`s:

```
namespace Types
{
    using Byte = std::uint8_t;      // From <cstdint>
    using UInt32 = std::uint32_t;
    using String = std::string;     // From <string>
}

// This is a vector of bytes loaded from a binary file.
using ByteBuffer = std::vector<Types::Byte>;    // From <vector>
```

Also assume the following constants:

```
namespace Constants
{
    const Types::String     G_BINARY_HEADER_STRING  = "A2FORMAT";
    const Types::Byte       G_BINARY_MAJOR_VERSION  = 0x00;
    const Types::Byte       G_BINARY_MINOR_VERSION  = 0x01;
    const Types::UInt32     G_BINARY_HEADER_SIZE    = 14;
}
```

Here is the binary-header-validating code:

```
bool isBufferValid (ByteBuffer &a_buffer)
{
    // Get the size of the buffer. Make a cursor here, too.
    Types::UInt32 l_size = a_buffer.size();
    Types::UInt32 l_cursor = 0;

    // Check to see if the size exceeds 14 bytes.
    if (l_size <= Constants::G_BINARY_HEADER_SIZE)
        return false;

    // Bytes #1 to #8 are the characters in the binary header string.
    for (l_cursor = 0; l_cursor < Constants::G_BINARY_HEADER_STRING.size(); ++l_cursor)
    {
        if (a_buffer.at(l_cursor) != Constants::G_BINARY_HEADER_STRING.at(l_cursor))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Byte #9 indicates the engine's major version.
    //
    // If the byte found doesn't match the current major version, then it is invalid.
    if (a_buffer.at(8) != Constants::G_BINARY_MAJOR_VERSION)
        return false;

    // Byte #10 indicates the engine's minor version.
    //
    // If this byte given is greater than the current minor version, then it is invalid.
    if (a_buffer.at(9) > Constants::G_BINARY_MINOR_VERSION)
        return false;

    // Bytes #11 through #14 make up a 32-bit unsigned integer that indicates how many
    // bytes of data reside after the binary header.
    //
    // These bytes are arranged in Little Endian Notation.
    Types::UInt32 l_sizeOfData = 0;
    for (Types::UInt32 i = 0, j = 10; j < 14; i++, j++)
        l_sizeOfData |= a_buffer.at(j) << (i * 8);

    // If the amount of bytes in the buffer, after the header, do not match the number found
    // in the integer above, then the buffer is invalid.
    if (l_size - Constants::G_BINARY_HEADER_SIZE != l_sizeOfData)
        return false;

    // Remove the header from the buffer, because it has been confirmed valid, and is
    // therefore ready to use.
    a_buffer.erase(a_buffer.begin(), a_buffer.begin() + Constants::G_BINARY_HEADER_SIZE);

    return true;
}
```

Is there anything I can do to make this code more efficient? Are there also any steps I can take to make this validation more effective?

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question as that might invalidate answers. I've rolled back the changes, and ask of you to read [what you may and may not do when receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765/78136)

Comment: Minor quibble: endianness isn't a notation _per se_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to make this code more efficient?

The first step is to ditch the `vector`, and specifically the `.erase` call at the end.

Calling `erase` on the head of a vector means performing a copy of the *full* buffer; it can, at best, be optimized to a `memmov`, but because of the header size (14 bytes) it cannot be vectorized, this really adds insult to injury.

In general, for parsing, I recommend using a *slice*: a lightweight container containing just the length of the content and a pointer to this content... owned by another container (maybe `vector`, maybe `unique_ptr<[]>`, ... ). Using a slice also allows abstracting the underlying storage, and that's sweet!

So, let's redefine `ByteBuffer` to:

```
template <typename T>
class Buffer {
public:
    ///
private:
    size_t size;
    T* data;
};

using ByteBuffer = Buffer<Byte const>;
```

Also, for style points, let's avoid modifying the arguments of the validation function. Since now `ByteBuffer` does not allocate, it comes at no extra cost:

```
boost::optional<ByteBuffer> check_and_strip_header(ByteBuffer const& input) {
}
```

Note: ideally, a variant `ByteBuffer` or `Error` would be the most expressive return, in a pinch `boost::optional<ByteBuffer>` just mimicks your current interface, and if not including boost matters, just returning an empty `ByteBuffer` on failure should work just fine... also then you lose the distinction between empty and failure.

Note: the type-freak in me would like to point out that using a different type for a raw buffer and the validated buffer would not be amiss either; a simple wrapper `MyFileType` containing a `ByteBuffer` for a result would help here. It would ensure that business logic supposed to be executed on a validated file cannot accidentally take a raw one instead.

> Are there also any steps I can take to make this validation more effective?

You are using a lot of manual loops, which may cost performance (unless the compiler recognizes it) and certainly hinders readability but more importantly there is a lot of repetition in the prefix checking, and since you are about to parse files this repetition will probably continue further.

So let us start with a few helper methods on `ByteBuffer`:

```
//  Checks whether input starts with prefix.
bool starts_with(ByteBuffer const& input, ByteBuffer const& prefix) {
    if (buffer.size() < prefix.size()) { return false; }

    return memcmp(input.data(), prefix.data(), prefix.size()) == 0;
}

//  Split the buffer into at the specified position.
//  If the position is out of range, returns (input, empty).
std::pair<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer> split_at(ByteBuffer const& input, size_t const pos) {
    if (pos > input.size()) { return std::make_pair(input, ByteBuffer()); }

    return std::make_pair(
        ByteBuffer(input.data(), pos),
        ByteBuffer(input.data() + pos, input.size() - pos)
    );
}

//  On success, returns the remaining bytes
//  On failure (if prefix isn't a prefix), returns none
boost::optional<ByteBuffer> strip_prefix(ByteBuffer const& input,
                                         ByteBuffer const& prefix)
{
    if (not starts_with(input, prefix)) { return boost::none; }

    return split_at(input, prefix.size()).second;
}

//  On success, returns (remaining bytes, number read).
//  On failure (buffer too short), returns (none, 0).
std::pair<boost::optional<ByteBuffer>, Types::UInt32> read_u32_le(ByteBuffer const& input) {
    if (input.size() < 4) { return std::make_pair(boost::none, 0); }

    auto const splitted = split_at(input, 4);

    //  Note: on a LE architecture, this should be optimized
    //        to a simple memcpy by the compiler (or better).
    Types::UInt32 const number =
        splitted.first[0] << (0 * 8) |
        splitted.first[1] << (1 * 8) |
        splitted.first[2] << (2 * 8) |
        splitted.first[3] << (3 * 8);

    return std::make_pair(splitted.second, number);
}
```

Now that we have the helper methods, we will also alter the set of constants: checking a single constant is faster than checking individual ones, and having a pre-calculated "total" length is risky in the face of change. So here we go:

```
namespace Constants {
    Byte const G_BINARY_HEADER_STORAGE[] = "A2FORMAT\x00\x01";

    ByteBuffer const G_BINARY_HEADER{G_BINARY_HEADER_STORAGE, sizeof(G_BINARY_HEADER_STORAGE)-1};
}
```

And now, let's go!

```
boost::optional<ByteBuffer> check_and_strip_header(ByteBuffer const& input) {
{
    //  Check the header string and version fields at once
    boost::optional<ByteBuffer> buffer = strip_prefix(input, G_BINARY_HEADER);

    if (not buffer) { return boost::none; }

    //  Check the size of the data
    Types::UInt32 l_sizeOfData = 0;
    std::tie(buffer, l_sizeOfData) = read_u32_le(*buffer);

    if (not buffer) { return boost::none; }

    if (buffer->size() != l_sizeOfData) { return boost::none; }

    //  Success!
    return buffer;
}
```

We are relying on the compiler to inline the necessary bits. This means that the definition of the helper methods should be `inline` in the `ByteBuffer` header file, to avoid the overhead of function calls.

Comment: "a lot of manual loops" there are two

Comment: Why do you rename the function to `check_and_strip_header` when it no longer strips?

Comment: `ByteBuffer const G_BINARY_HEADER =
        ByteBuffer(G_BINARY_HEADER_STORAGE, sizeof(G_BINARY_HEADER_STORAGE));` Why copy-initialisation? Just `ByteBuffer const G_BINARY_HEADER{G_BINARY_HEADER_STORAGE, sizeof(G_BINARY_HEADER_STORAGE)};` is clearer and more direct. It also does not require the type to be copy-constructible.

Comment: `read_u32_le` contains a syntax error in one of the comments (and this is indicated by the syntax highlighter)

Comment: `check_and_strip_header` is now quite hard to follow. At least add some more comments but I found the OP's original code to be much easier to read.

Comment: Finally, I think you know what I'm going to think of using `not` instead of `!` ;)

Comment: @PreferenceBean: I personally prefer `not` to `!` because it occupies more space which makes it more noticeable; for example `!ol` is being very close to `lol` graphically. As for `check_and_strip_header`... I am very bad at naming, but I would still contend that it does strip: the result is shorter than the input.

Comment: Without Boost, you could check for failure by checking to see if the data pointer in the returned buffer is null, right? `bool Buffer::isError() const { return data == nullptr; }`

Comment: @Dennis: You could yes, note then that a default constructed before is "in error". Whether it works for you... is up to you :)

Answer (score 12):

The most unforgivable fault with this function is that calling `isValidBuffer()` also erases the buffer! That completely violates the Principle of Least Surprise. If anything, the parameter should be `const`.

Comment: It doesn't erase the whole buffer, though. It only erases the first 14 bytes of the buffer, which is the binary header that has, by that point, been confirmed to be a valid buffer by the program. Regardless, I will make that a const parameter and outsource that task from the function.

Comment: It's still unforgivable. If a method is named `isSomething()`, my expectation is that it returns true or false with no side-effects.

Comment: I wouldn't erase it _at all_. Its size is negligible but you're requiring a move of every single byte of your payload. Just start examining your data from where the header left off.